# Error in getting installed software on local network systems !! Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

```
        Dim wmins = (&quot;//192.168.1.5/root/cimv2&quot;)
        objOS = New ManagementObjectSearcher(wmins, &quot;SELECT * FROM Win32_OperatingSystem &quot;)
        objCS = New ManagementObjectSearcher(wmins, &quot;SELECT * FROM Win32_ComputerSystem&quot;)
        objPR = New ManagementObjectSearcher(wmins, &quot;SELECT * FROM Win32_Processor&quot;)
        objHS = New ManagementObjectSearcher(wmins, &quot;SELECT * FROM Win32_DiskDrive&quot;)
        objIS = New ManagementObjectSearcher(wmins, &quot;SELECT * FROM Win32_Product&quot;)
        For Each objMgmt In objOS.Get
                    The error is: Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))


            m_strOSName = objMgmt(&quot;name&quot;).ToString()
            m_strOSVersion = objMgmt(&quot;version&quot;).ToString()
            m_strComputerName = objMgmt(&quot;csname&quot;).ToString()
            m_strWindowsDir = objMgmt(&quot;windowsdirectory&quot;).ToString()
        Next
```

I just want to list all installed software's on my local area systems that's all

Answer (score 0):

I think you have no rights to access the path which you want to access. PLease check the access rights of your machine.

Comment: where and how can i check it. Pls tell me the steps

Comment: in local area system check the folder rights by right click on folder and in security tab you have to give full control to IIS user